# "The reason for you to ... is ...." What is the question form of this?

Tags: question-tags

For example: "The reason for you to be in jail is you murdered someone"

If I want to verify it, how can I state it as a question?

"Is the reason for you to be in jail you murdered someone?"

this sound a little weird but is that true?

By the way, I don't want to ask it like I know nothing, like: "What is the reason....?"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add one word to what you have:

> Is the reason for you to be in jail ***that*** you murdered someone?

The statement can also be expressed that way:

> The reason for you to be in jail is ***that*** you murdered someone.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is better to ask

> Are you in jail because you murdered someone?

In the end, it is more important to retain the correct meaning rather than the correct wording.

Comment: I would like to accept this one as a solution too but I can only have one :( But I really liked the way you think

Answer (score 0):

You might say:

> Is it murder the reason why you've been arrested/put in jail?
>
> Have you been put in jail because you murdered somebody?
>
> Are you in jail because you've been charged with murder?
>
> Are you in jail because you've murdered someone?

As a matter of fact there are several ways to say that and some will certainly fit what you're looking for.